# Problem with Procfile / wsgi when deploying to heroku with python flask app ~ Failed to find attribute

Tags: python, heroku, flask, wsgi

> boiler-plate-code: [My Github Repo](https://github.com/nubonics/myapi)

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myapi:create_app --log-file -
```

Heroku logs:

```
2020-01-25T11:07:56.952951+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn myapi:create_app --log-file -`
2020-01-25T11:07:59.205710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-01-25T11:07:58.973586+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-25 11:07:58 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-01-25T11:07:58.974163+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-25 11:07:58 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:27984 (4)
2020-01-25T11:07:58.974256+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-25 11:07:58 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-01-25T11:07:58.979663+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-25 11:07:58 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2020-01-25T11:07:58.983867+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'create_app' in 'myapi'.
2020-01-25T11:07:58.984029+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-25 11:07:58 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2020-01-25T11:07:58.993260+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-25 11:07:58 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-01-25T11:07:58.997526+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'create_app' in 'myapi'.
2020-01-25T11:07:58.997674+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-25 11:07:58 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-01-25T11:07:59.123159+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-25 11:07:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-01-25T11:07:59.123241+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-25 11:07:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
2020-01-25T11:07:59.187524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 4
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

from os import environ 

from .commands import create_users, create_database
from .extensions import db, guard
from .models import User 
from .routes import api 


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
    app.config['JWT_ACCESS_LIFESPAN'] = {'minutes': 30}

    db.init_app(app)
    guard.init_app(app, User)

    app.cli.add_command(create_users)
    app.cli.add_command(create_database)

    app.register_blueprint(api)

    return app
```

> not really sure a better way of doing this, however, [imgur_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnSrU.jpg) is where you will find the directory setup I have for my project.

My problem is, that I cannot figure out how to deploy to heroku. I am attempting to use gunicorn as a webservice, as this is needed when deploying to heroku. Could really use some help to figure out how to do so / find the correct code for my Procfile...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: [The flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/) have a link to "deploying flask on heroku". Have you read that yet?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes. This defers to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python which I have followed, however, I am still facing this problem of being unable to locate the correct Procfile contents.

Comment: `web: gunicorn myapi:create_app()`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your directory layout.

Comment: @Chris ```2020-01-25T14:10:32.330979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn myapi:create_app() --log-file -`
2020-01-25T14:10:34.122325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-01-25T14:10:34.066209+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
2020-01-25T14:10:34.066232+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: -c: line 0: `gunicorn myapi:create_app() --log-file -'
```

Comment: @Sparrow, what does that have to do with my comment about showing us your directory layout?

Comment: (Though that's now a different error message. What is the _actual_ error message that you're seeing?)

Comment: @Chris https://github.com/nubonics/myapi

Comment: @Chris that is the error after changing the Procfile to what you suggested.

Comment: @Sparrow, I didn't suggest any change to your `Procfile`, but I now see a comment from v25 suggesting a change. That's a bad suggestion. There shouldn't be any parentheses there. // I asked you to put the directory structure _in your question_, not for a link to GitHub. Questions are supposed to be self-contained.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206634/discussion-between-sparrow-and-chris).

Answer (score 2):

Solved with:
Procfile: gunicorn "myapi:create_app()" --log-file -
Please note, quotations are required.